# Why is it $V_i=V_\mathrm{max} \sin θ$ instead of $V_i=V_\mathrm{max}\cos θ$? (AC sinusoidal waveform)

Tags: electromagnetism

The math is trivial, but I don't get why it should be true.  It seems that at 90° and 270° a loop would have exactly ZERO flux running through the loop, not max.  The magnetic field lines should be in the exact same plane as the loop resulting in nothing through the loop.  At  0/360° and 180° the loop seems to me where it would be normal to the max number of field lines resulting in max voltage.  What am I missing?

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/sinusoidal-waveform.html

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. It's considered better form around here to make questions self-standing, without the need to read another web site just to understand the question.  We are volunteering our time ...

Comment: I appreciate you for volunteering your time which is why I put all the relevant information here. I also gave credit to a site that I used their graphics to illustrate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electromotive force (can be interpreted as voltage here) through a loop caused by a magnetic field is related to the **change** in the magnetic flux through the loop, and **not** the value of the flux through the loop.  The emf is written as

$V_{emf} = -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$

When it is at $90^{\circ}$, even though the flux is zero, the rate of change of the flux at that point is at a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

At points A and E, the electrons in the wire are moving parallel to the magnetic field, so the cross product (v X B) is zero; so the graph looks right to me.